# Difference between !IsPostBack and refresh in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written some codes in `!IsPostBack` block. This code is getting executed when the page loads for the first time. That is fine. But the problem is, when I refresh the page by hitting the <kbd>f5</kbd> key this executes again which I don't want to do. I have searched many articles and found difference between `PostBack` and refresh. I know about this. But my question is difference between `!IsPostBack` and Refresh. Can we write some code which executes only when the page loads for the 1st time not when we refresh the page. By the way I have written my `!IsPostBack` block inside `Page_Init()` method and I am using c# for codebehind. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refersh and IsPostback are somewhat unrelated:

- Refresh in browser generally mean "re-run last action that resulted in this page". Usually it causes GET request, but it as well can cause POST if page was shown as result of postback. Side note: you often can find sites warning you not to refresh page during non-reversible operations like "charge my credit card" as it may trigger duplicate post.
- IsPostBack simply states that request come to server as POST, not GET.

Combining that you can get Refresh that triggers either branch of `if (IsPostBack)` check. In most cases so server will receive GET request and hence execute `!IsPostBack` branch.

If you really need to detect if page was rendered once already - setting cookie or writing information into `Session` would be reasonable solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please change your code behind code as given below.

```
        Boolean IsPageRefresh;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["postids"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                Session["postid"] = ViewState["postids"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (ViewState["postids"].ToString() != Session["postid"].ToString())
                {
                    IsPageRefresh = true;
                }
                Session["postid"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ViewState["postids"] = Session["postid"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ispostback will always false if you are refreshing after first load!! so never comes in else until one post back from the page

Comment: @Aristos the code is not for Javascript. It works well from C#

Comment: @MAK not at al. It will comes in the else part.

Comment: @Aristos Sorry. I didn't get

Comment: @NCA dont worry, forget it, I delete the msgs